PYSPARK : df.show() failed to run at 2nd run
During the first run for creating data frame in spark is successful,df.show() can output the data frame with no errors, but during the second run it failed but the code is still the same
first run
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate() 

from datetime import datetime, date
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import Row

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(a=1, b=2., c='string1', d=date(2000, 1, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0)),
    Row(a=2, b=3., c='string2', d=date(2000, 2, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 2, 12, 0)),
    Row(a=4, b=5., c='string3', d=date(2000, 3, 1), e=datetime(2000, 1, 3, 12, 0))
])
df

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 2., 'string1', date(2000, 1, 1), datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0)),
    (2, 3., 'string2', date(2000, 2, 1), datetime(2000, 1, 2, 12, 0)),
    (3, 4., 'string3', date(2000, 3, 1), datetime(2000, 1, 3, 12, 0))
], schema='a long, b double, c string, d date, e timestamp')
df

pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [2., 3., 4.],
    'c': ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'],
    'd': [date(2000, 1, 1), date(2000, 2, 1), date(2000, 3, 1)],
    'e': [datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0), datetime(2000, 1, 2, 12, 0), datetime(2000, 1, 3, 12, 0)]
})
df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
df

# All DataFrames above result same.
df.show()
df.printSchema()

it gives this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 2
      1 # All DataFrames above result same.
----> 2 df.show()
      3 df.printSchema()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\pyspark-env-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:899, in DataFrame.show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    893     raise PySparkTypeError(
    894         error_class="NOT_BOOL",
    895         message_parameters={"arg_name": "vertical", "arg_type": type(vertical).__name__},
    896     )
    898 if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 899     print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    900 else:
    901     try:

File ~\anaconda3\envs\pyspark-env-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File ~\anaconda3\envs\pyspark-env-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:169, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    167 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    168     try:
--> 169         return f(*a, **kw)
    170     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    171         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\pyspark-env-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o421.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (PainPeko executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(PlainSocketImpl.java:163)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:474)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:551)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:519)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:190)
    ... 32 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2856)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2792)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3060)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2994)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2983)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2419)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:530)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:483)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:4332)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:3314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:4322)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:546)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:4320)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:4320)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:3314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:3537)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:315)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(PlainSocketImpl.java:163)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:474)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:551)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:519)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:190)
    ... 32 more

i tried remove the kernel cache and reupload the file but still did not work

Does adding spark.stop() at the end of the script help?

Is the code running via a Juptyer notebook? Are you running it via a Windows machine?

It has been solve thanks, the problem lies in the data frame creation where it could not read the data given
